# Synchronize drawing a rectangle using mouse event propagation

Tags: c++, qt

I have a base class `MainWidget` which inherites `QOpenGLWidget`. `MainWidget` has 2 child classes `ColorWidget` and `BWWidget`. I wish to synchronize drawing a rectangle between both the child widgets i.e. when i start drawing a shape on `ColorWidget` the shape should show up on `BWWidget`. I have overwritten `mouseMoveEvent` for base class to draw rectangles.

```
void MainWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if(m_mousePressed && event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        // check some conditions
        if (/*conditions*/)
        {
            m_activeItem.reset(new Rectangle(this));

            m_activeItem->show();
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to draw rectangles on the child classes individually. But i want them to be drawn simultaneously. I have tried to overwrite `mouseMoveEvent`for both child classes but it seems calling `MainWidget::mouseMoveEvent()` from child classes will lead to infinite loop and a crash.

In my case, parent to `ColorWidget` and `BWWidget` is a `QDockWidget` and my `Rectangle` class inherits `QLabel`.

Not sure how can i implement this.

Comment: As you mentioned `QOpenGLWidget`, you could do rendering of same data with different fragment shaders (where shader for B/W image mixes colors to gray scales).

Comment: All of this would be quite trivial had you used `QGraphicsScene` to hold the shape, and `QGraphicsView` to display it. A `QLabel` isn't some generic "rectangle", and certainly it has nothing to do with the other widgets other than perhaps being their child. Could you please explain the functionality you want? What is the **behavior the user is expecting**, and what is the purpose of it? There most likely is a very simple solution that involves nothing that your question would suggest - you're so centered on a wrong solution that you forgot the real problem. C.f. XY Problem.

Comment: @KubaOber You may be right about my execution of solution. I will try to explain it briefly, I have a `QMainWindow` with 2 `QDockWidgets`. Dockwidgets contain openglwidgets (ColorWidget & BWWidget) which i am painting `QImage` using `QPainter` and `paintEvent()`. Now, i want to select objects in the image by drawing Rectangles on the widgets.  I chose this to get OpenGL acceleration while painting overlays on the widgets. I may be wrong may be there is a better solution to this.

Comment: Keeping in mind that i would be extending this to drawing Circles and Polygons using mouse.

Comment: Don't accelerate before getting it working properly. The performance of the plain old painter should be more than sufficient. You can put both the image and the transient rectangle on the scene, and the views will all display it for you. Also remember that accelerating just the overlay is pointless: the overlay costs next to nothing to draw. The expensive part is rendering the image.

Comment: So you mean i just inherit from `QGraphicsView` instead of `QOpenGLWidget`. Then implement drawing rectangles on it?  If you can post a small snippet as how can i achieve this would be wonderful.

Comment: You inherit from nothing. You **use** the view. It already works, there's nothing to change there. You can read the documentation on how to switch the view to use an OpenGL-backed renderer, IIRC you switch the `viewport` to the OpenGL widget but do read about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand 100% what you are asking here (mainly because you didn't provide a minimal compilable example), this is what I understood:

- You have two widgets,

  - one of type `class ColorWidget : public MainWidget`
  - one of `class BWWidget : public MainWidget`
  - with `class MainWidget : public QOpenGLWidget`
- These two widgets are visible side-by-side.
- When either one of your two widgets receives a `mouseMoveEvent()`, both should display something.

If that's what you have, these are your options:

1. First of all, you should move functionality to create a rectangle out of your mouse move event handler (e.g. into a function `MainWidget::DrawMouseMoveRectangle(QPoint pos)`.

   - Doing so already makes accidental recursive calls less likely.
2. (possible:) Make both widgets known to each other (e.g. via `QPointer<MainWidget> pOther`).

   - Override `mouseMoveEvent()` and call `DrawMouseMoveRectangle(QPoint pos)` for `this` and `pOther`.
3. (better:) Since you're already using Qt, create a signal `MainWidget::SignalMouseMove(QPoint p)` and slot `MainWidget::MouseMovedSlot(QPoint p)`.

   - In your common parent widget's initilization you connect both widgets' slots to each widgets' signal (see below).
   - In MainWidget's `mouseMoveEvent()` do `emit SignalMouseMove(evt->pos)`*

     - (*) Probably you need to pass some context for correct interpretation of the geometry.
   - Now both functions get called independent of the widget which received the event.

How to make the connections:

```
bool ok = true;
ok = ok && connect(w1, &MainWidget::SignalMouseMove, w1, &MainWidget::MouseMovedSlot);
ok = ok && connect(w1, &MainWidget::SignalMouseMove, w2, &MainWidget::MouseMovedSlot);
ok = ok && connect(w2, &MainWidget::SignalMouseMove, w1, &MainWidget::MouseMovedSlot);
ok = ok && connect(w2, &MainWidget::SignalMouseMove, w2, &MainWidget::MouseMovedSlot);
Q_ASSERT(ok);
```

**EDIT**

Answering your comment:

> What i want is i should be able to draw 1 Rectangle and pass it on to every other widget to show it (with appropriate geometry) because it will enable me for moving and resizing will reflect on all widgets.

Displaying the same instance of a widget in two different parent widgets *may* be possible, but definitely feels like a kludge and is not how Qt is designed.

You should take a look at [Qt's model-view-programming](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html), because this is essentially what you want to achieve:

- Have a single model displayed in two views.
- Update both views on any change of the model.

Because implementing [`QAbstractItemModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) is a bit overkill for that, here are some alternatives:

- Use [Qt's Graphics View Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html): Display the same `QGraphicsScene` in two `QGraphicsView`s and put some `QGraphicsRectItem` into the scene.
- Use Qt's parameter support for semi-automatic data binding.
- Roll your own, it isn't that hard:

  - Basically, you have to separate your *view* logic from your *model* logic into e.g. `RectangleView` and `RectangleModel`.
  - Then make the two connectable, e.g. via Signals in the model and Slots in the view(s).
  - Create a view in both your widgets.
  - Give each widget a shared pointer to a model.
  - Connect the model with both views.
  - Result: Whenever you change the model (from which widget doesn't matter), both views will be updated.

**EDIT 2: *very* simple example using a shared QGraphicsRectItem**

```
// this is a minimal compilable example of two views sharing the same model, with automatic update on mouse events
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

class TestWidget : public QWidget
{
    //Q_OBJECT // Not neccessary here because we don't use and don't need moc for this example. -> Don't try this at home!
public:
    TestWidget() : QWidget(Q_NULLPTR),
        lt(new QHBoxLayout(this)),
        v1(new QGraphicsView(this)),
        v2(new QGraphicsView(this)),
        s(new QGraphicsScene(this)),
        r(Q_NULLPTR)
    {
        // initialization
        r = s->addRect(0, 0, 10, 10, QPen(Qt::red), Qt::yellow);

        lt->addWidget(v1);
        lt->addWidget(v2);

        // sharing the same model:
        v1->setScene(s);
        v2->setScene(s);
        // in reality, you need to share QGraphicsRectItem *r, too.
        // (it would actually be sufficient to share *r only)

        // very simple mouse interaction:
        v1->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
        v1->viewport()->setMouseTracking(true);
        v2->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
        v2->viewport()->setMouseTracking(true);
    }

    bool eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *evt) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        QGraphicsView *gv = Q_NULLPTR;
        if(o == v1->viewport())
        {
            gv = v1;
        }
        else if(o == v2->viewport())
        {
            gv = v2;
        }

        if(gv != Q_NULLPTR)
        {
            QPointF p;
            switch(evt->type())
            {
            case QEvent::MouseMove:
                p = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(evt)->pos();
                evt->accept();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            if(p != QPoint())
            {
                // do something different depending on interacting view - just for demonstration
                if(gv == v1)
                {
                    r->setRect(QRectF(p, r->rect().bottomRight()));
                }
                else
                {
                    r->setRect(QRectF(r->rect().topLeft(), p));
                }
            }
        }
        return QWidget::eventFilter(o, evt);
    }

private:
    QHBoxLayout *lt;
    QGraphicsView *v1;
    QGraphicsView *v2;
    QGraphicsScene *s;
    QGraphicsRectItem *r;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    TestWidget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: going with option 3. I believe `w1` and `w2` are child class objects. But i already have them instantiated in my `QMainWindow` with `QDockWidget` as their parent. I am not sure if it is a good idea to create more than one instance. So, bit confused how can i use signal/slots here?

Comment: I used 'w1' and 'w2' simply as placeholders because I don't know the name of your widgets - like `ColorWidget *myWidget` or `ui.colorWidget` or whatever.

Comment: i tried your approach it works. There is a problem here. Connecting each widget to the slot creates instance of `Rectangle`. What i want is i should be able to draw 1 `Rectangle` and pass it on to every other widget to show it (with appropriate geometry) because it will enable me for `moving` and `resizing` will reflect on all widgets. I tried passing the created `Rectangle` by emitting a signal on `mouseReleaseEvent` and using `show()` but i cannot see the `Rectangle`.

Comment: This looks promising. So in this case `RectangleView` should inherit from `QGraphicsView` and `RectangleModel` from `QGraphicsScene`?

Comment: This is a very nice idea but i am struggling to implement it. Could you please post a small snippet as how i can achieve that? I can understand it much better.

Comment: @MarKS I added an example.